# Rename a Gulp.js task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, task, rename, gulp

Imagine I have a project "A" which is built with `Gulp.js` with a "default" task. I want to reuse the same task in a project "B" but I want to define my own "default" task there as well. In Grunt we can rename a task like this

```
gulp.renameTask('default', 'projectADefault')
```

in order to accomplish that. Is that also possible with `Gulp.js`? What's the workaround if not?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Could you code you give a small example of what you are trying to do? If this task is big and important enough, it should be spun out into it's own module that both gulp files can import and use (A would import it and assign it to default, B would import it and assign it to whatever).

Comment: Project "A" inlcudes static resources (HTML, JS, CSS) with its corresponding default tasks like concatenation, minification etc. Project "B" is using these static resources to further processes the outcome to create a plattoform specific theme. It's important to keep the workflow for developers simple in this case. I can extract these tasks in its own module as you recommend and assign them to the "default" task for project "A" exclusively. This extracted module can then be assign later in Project "B" to "default" again.

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://realguess.net/2014/07/13/gulp-task-alias/

Comment: @TongShen that was exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!